# Mobile - offline web-app and audioclips storage

Tags: iphone, web-applications, offline

I built a simple soundboard free app for Android. Some customers asked me when that app will be available for iPhone too. 
Now, I'm thinking about developing the soundboard as a web-app that works offline. Is it possible to do? Is it possible for a web-app to store locally and permanently some audio files?

The size of these audio files ranges from 16kb to 150kb, for a total of 2,5mb (50 audioclips).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by downloading the video files when the app installed in first time to the documents folder and show it from there

Comment: I can think a solution: storing the audioclips as blob fields into a web SQL database. Is it possible? I mean, what kind of fields can be created for that kind of DB?